# image.Decode results in "unknown format" when source is multipart.File

Tags: image, go, martini

I have a `multipart.File` that a user uploads to my server, and then I take that file and upload it to s3 using `aws-sdk-go`, but I also want to create a thumbnail of that image.

The code below works fine in my tests when I `file` is the return value of an `os.Open(...` of a local file, but it hit's the `err` block when I send `CreateThumbnail` the same variable I sent to [`s3`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/blob/master/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go#L184), which asks for an `io.Reader`

```
import (
  "image"
  "image/jpeg"
)
func UploadToS3(file multipart.File, /*snip*/) {
  _, uploadErr := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
    Body:   file,
    ContentType: aws.String(mimeType),
    ACL: aws.String("public-read"),
  })
  reader, err := CreateThumbnail(file)
}    

func CreateThumbnail(imageFile io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
  decodedImage, _, err := image.Decode(imageFile)
  if err != nil {
   fmt.Println("Error decoding", err, decodedImage) // "unknown format"
   return nil, err
 }
 /*snip*/
```

Most of the answers I see for the problem involve adding `import _ "image/jpeg"`, but that's already imported (as well as `png` and `gif`).
I'm fairly new to Golang, so I'm a bit lost as to what I'm doing wrong. I tried `image.Decode(bufio.NewReader(imageFile))` as well, but that results in the same `err`.

Comment: You could debug this by making sure the multipart.File really is a jpeg: Check the first handful of bytes.

Comment: @Volker It's not, the first 2 bytes are not 'FF D8'. I can send that variable to s3 and it get's saved as an image, how can I do the same locally without `image.Decode(imageFile)`?

Comment: No idea. If you could post the let's say first 100 bytes someone might recognise it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call `uploader.Upload` reads to the end of the file. Seek back to the beginning of the file before calling `CreateThumbnail`:

```
func UploadToS3(file multipart.File, /*snip*/) {
  _, uploadErr := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
    Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
    Key:    aws.String(key),
    Body:   file,
    ContentType: aws.String(mimeType),
    ACL: aws.String("public-read"),
  })
  // Seek back to beginning of file for CreateThumbnail
  if _, err := file.Seek(0, 0); err != nil {
    // handle error
  }
  reader, err := CreateThumbnail(file)
}
```

Comment: This work as long as I changed the parameter type to `multipart.File` (since that implements `io.Reader` and `io.Seeker`). Thanks @ThunderCat